# Is something forcing the FullCalendar to scroll to the top?

Tags: fullcalendar

in $(document).ready I'm adding a class to one of the #calendar tr's to represent the "current" time, then I'm calling the jQuery function scrollTop() to scroll .fc-agenda-body to that position. It works, but it looks as though .fc-agenda-body is being force back to the top after the events render. Can I unbind this event somehow OR is there an event I can bind to once ALL of the calendar events have been rendered?

Comment: do you have the `firstHour` property set?

Comment: Haha, I thought that wouldn't allow me to scroll up. You win ;)

Comment: if you don't want the user to scroll up try using minTime instead. I've made my comment into an answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `firstHour` property set, which determines which hour the calendar will initially display, it won't prevent the user from scrolling up.

If you want to prevent that, then use `minTime` instead.

Comment: Is there any way to call 'firstHour' after the fullCalendar has been created? I only want it to just to the current hour when the selected date is today.